# Installing my sql

Tags: mysql, installation

Previously I installed mysql in my system and  I uninstalled it after some time.
Now I want to install it again, but it asked for the previous password. My friend told that i have to delete a file manually to complete uninstall, but he dont knows the path of the file, Help me in this issue. I am using Windos Xp

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,91628,207786#msg-207786

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to delete your `MySQL`directory manually?

Could be located in `C:\Program Files\MySQL` or `C:\MySQL` for example.